# Issues parsing GenBank file info into R

Tags: r, list, bioinformatics, dataformat

Bioconductor package functions for parsing GenBank files into R never seem to work for bacterial genomes (nobody cares about us microbiologists, I guess), so I've written the following code to read in a GBFF file line-by-line and start extracting FEATURE header information from https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCA/000/008/685/GCA_000008685.2_ASM868v2/GCA_000008685.2_ASM868v2_genomic.gbff.gz

```
library(tidyverse)

# read gbff file with readLines and split into a list of separate genbank records 
readGBFF <- function (file, text = readLines(file), verbose = FALSE){
  if (is(text, "character")) {
    split_indices <- cumsum(grepl("^LOCUS", text))
    text <- base::split(text, split_indices)
  }
  return(text)
}

GBFFraw <- readGBFF("GCA_000008685.2_ASM868v2_genomic.gbff.gz")

# assign accession numbers to the names of each genbank record 
names(GBFFraw) <- sapply(GBFFraw, function(x) {
  version_line <- x[grep("^VERSION", x)]
  gsub("VERSION\\s+", "", version_line)
})

# capture the features for each genbank record 
GBFFfeat <- lapply(GBFFraw, function(x) {
  i_start <- grep("^FEATURES", x)
  i_end <- grep("^ORIGIN", x)
  paste0(x[(i_start[1]+1):(i_end[1]-1)])
})
```

From the GBFFfeat list (example of list element below), I would like to make a dataframe like this:
[image: dataframe example]

```
> GBFFfeat$AE000790.2
  [1] "     source          1..53657"                                                   
  [2] "                     /organism=\"Borreliella burgdorferi B31\""                  
  [3] "                     /mol_type=\"genomic DNA\""                                  
  [4] "                     /strain=\"B31\""                                            
  [5] "                     /type_material=\"type strain of Borrelia burgdorferi\""     
  [6] "                     /db_xref=\"taxon:224326\""                                  
  [7] "                     /plasmid=\"lp54\""                                          
  [8] "     gene            652..1137"                                                  
  [9] "                     /locus_tag=\"BB_A01\""                                      
 [10] "                     /note=\"outer membrane protein P13; this gene contains a"   
 [11] "                     frame shift which may be the result of a sequencing error;" 
 [12] "                     identified by match to protein family HMM PF05628\""        
 [13] "                     /pseudo"                                                    
 [14] "     gene            1461..1970"                                                 
 [15] "                     /locus_tag=\"BB_A03\""                                      
 [16] "     CDS             1461..1970"                                                 
 [17] "                     /locus_tag=\"BB_A03\""                                      
 [18] "                     /codon_start=1"                                             
 [19] "                     /transl_table=11"                                           
 [20] "                     /product=\"outer membrane protein\""                        
 [21] "                     /protein_id=\"AAC66227.1\""                                 
 [22] "                     /translation=\"MKKTIIVFIILAFMLNCKNKSNDAEPNNDLDEKSQAKSNLVDED"
 [23] "                     RIEFSKATPLEKLVSRLNLNNTEKETLTFLTNLLKEKLVDPNIGLHFKNSGGDESKIE" 
 [24] "                     ESVQKFLSELKEDEIKDLLAKIKENKDKKEKDPEELNTYKSILASGFDGIFNQADSKT" 
 [25] "                     TLNKLKDTI\""                                                
 [26] "     gene            complement(2045..2893)"                                     
 [27] "                     /locus_tag=\"BB_A04\""                                      
 [28] "     CDS             complement(2045..2893)"                                     
 [29] "                     /locus_tag=\"BB_A04\""                                      
 [30] "                     /codon_start=1"                                             
 [31] "                     /transl_table=11"                                           
 [32] "                     /product=\"S2 antigen\""                                    
 [33] "                     /protein_id=\"AAC66228.1\""                                 
 [34] "                     /translation=\"MKRVIVSFVVLILGCNLDDNSKMERKGSNKLIRESGSDRRGQEN"
 [35] "                     RALGAMNFGLFSGDSGVVYDLQNYETLKALENKNKFIDYSKIEFLEGTKSINAFIWAV" 
 [36] "                     SVRWIKIKARDLFGECGDFIKELKGIKYSYLVSPVDGSYISYAMPIIVFETTRESDPL" 
 [37] "                     YSVSGFKLISKGNDINFNENKSGFWGRLPMSEKSVESGLVTAYPFGSSDAKKVIEAFA" 
 [38] "                     SLYNNGTWSDMIAEITIKSKQYPKNEKVYRITLDSQLFNVAMKKIIEKYPKIKSASFA" 
 [39] "                     FNSLIN\""                                                   
 [40] "     gene            complement(3003..4256)"                                     
 [41] "                     /locus_tag=\"BB_A05\""                                      
 [42] "     CDS             complement(3003..4256)"                                     
 [43] "                     /locus_tag=\"BB_A05\""                                      
 [44] "                     /codon_start=1"                                             
 [45] "                     /transl_table=11"                                           
 [46] "                     /product=\"S1 antigen\""                                    
 [47] "                     /protein_id=\"AAC66229.1\""                                 
 [48] "                     /translation=\"MNKIGIAFIISFLLFVNCKGKSLEEDLKSTTSNNKQNLISNEKK"
 [49] "                     SLNSKNNRLKDSRLSNFESKKNDQTLKKSKDFKKDLQTLRNSKNLMPKDLDQSSNDFE" 
 [50] "                     NLDNSESLQEASSKHNIGKSRYGKALLKNDHDEIWIPHLNLEEDKNFEFFKKSLQNDE" 
 [51] "                     NRYALGGWLLNNDEVLVKYRYSEKDVNQFLIDIGKKRWGDLSSKMSTLVRLIGNYSDK" 
 [52] "                     SDREDEISLLDMNLCQQFYLTKINAGGSSADILVALEKTIDQQISGVSKELLELKNFS" 
 [53] "                     LTTKSELDWYLNWKRNLTDEEEETLQCCRVLLGGELDFENLDDLFKRLGKEYSRLILR" 
 [54] "                     KLEEITLNYDVNRFLKEMEKSRKSFKQALGSIRNKSKRVVIFKVRNSLLEIFKLYYNN" 
 [55] "                     IGRNKKLYDYINRMLNSLIKEISRR\""                                
 [56] "     gene            complement(4667..5140)"                                     
 [57] "                     /locus_tag=\"BB_A07\""                                      
 [58] "     CDS             complement(4667..5140)"                                     
 [59] "                     /locus_tag=\"BB_A07\""                                      
 [60] "                     /codon_start=1"                                             
 [61] "                     /transl_table=11"                                           
 [62] "                     /product=\"chpAI protein, putative\""                       
 [63] "                     /protein_id=\"AAC66230.2\""                                 
 [64] "                     /translation=\"MKNILLFVILLFFSCKEFNYSDLRRRPSKVLNASNGASNKELKI"
 [65] "                     SFVDSLNDDQKEALFFLEQVVLDSNPDKFNQIFNLNEEKVKEMLVTVVKCLKAKRKAK" 
 [66] "                     MALESSNVANVANAKQQLLQVEKTYIDNLRQSFMTTKNIEEACNLVKNYDASASF\""  
 [67] "     gene            5314..5649"                                                 
 [68] "                     /locus_tag=\"BB_A08\""                                      
 [69] "     CDS             5314..5649"                                                 
 [70] "                     /locus_tag=\"BB_A08\""                                      
 [71] "                     /note=\"identified by match to protein family HMM PF07115\""
 [72] "                     /codon_start=1"                                             
 [73] "                     /transl_table=11"                                           
 [74] "                     /product=\"conserved hypothetical protein\""                
 [75] "                     /protein_id=\"AAC66231.1\""                                 
 [76] "                     /translation=\"MEIKIDEKFNIVFNNDLKLIENIEEQKQRLFFYLKTPKGSLKEN"
 [77] "                     PNYGLDYSFYFKLCKANKLESIKNFFLNLSKELKIDLINVRPSIKNKTITINFFFLGK" 
 [78] "                     DNLKMDFKI\""
```

I have no idea how to do this from the current list formatting. I can use regex expressions to find specific identifiers like "source", "gene", and "CDS", but I'm lost on how to make it into a dataframe. My dataframe example only shows the information I need, but maybe it would be easier to just capture everything based on white spacing and characters like "/" and "="? Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty big problem. My attempt here.
Some comments:
In your example you fill the "plasmid" column down, i don't known the criteria used there, but you can "fill" the column using the tidyr::fill function (see coments)
I include all tags as columns, binding them with bind_rows. Please filter what you need.

hope may be helpful.

```r
library(tidyverse)


url <- "https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCA/000/008/685/GCA_000008685.2_ASM868v2/GCA_000008685.2_ASM868v2_genomic.gbff.gz"
file <- basename(url)

download.file(url, destfile = file)

# read gbff file with readLines and split into a list of separate genbank records 
readGBFF <- function (file, text = readLines(file), verbose = FALSE){
  if (is(text, "character")) {
    split_indices <- cumsum(grepl("^LOCUS", text))
    text <- base::split(text, split_indices)
  }
  return(text)
}

GBFFraw <- readGBFF("GCA_000008685.2_ASM868v2_genomic.gbff.gz")

# assign accession numbers to the names of each genbank record 
names(GBFFraw) <- sapply(GBFFraw, function(x) {
  version_line <- x[grep("^VERSION", x)]
  gsub("VERSION\\s+", "", version_line)
})

# capture the features for each genbank record 
GBFFfeat <- lapply(GBFFraw, function(x) {
  i_start <- grep("^FEATURES", x)
  i_end <- grep("^ORIGIN", x)
  paste0(x[(i_start[1]+1):(i_end[1]-1)])
})

# check length of fixet space being consistent among list of lists
range(sapply(GBFFfeat, function(x) {
  max(sapply(gregexpr("^ +", GBFFfeat$AE000790.2), attr, "match.length")) }))
#> [1] 21 21
# 21 21  it is consistently 21

GBFF_df <- mapply(GBFFfeat, names(GBFFfeat), FUN = function(elem, seqid){

  #check first row is not empty
  stopifnot(!grepl("^ {21}" , elem[[1]]))  
  # identify rows 
  rows <- cumsum(!grepl(elem, pattern ="^ {21}"))
  elem_list <- split(elem, rows)


  row_list <- lapply(elem_list, function(text){
    #remove first line of each block and make one single line
    block <- paste(substring(text[-1], 22, nchar(text[-1])), collapse = " ")    
    #identify sequences /tagname="content"
    matches = gregexec("/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)(?:=(\"[^\"]+\"|[a-zA-Z0-9_]+))?", block)
    
    #separate values and tagnames and remove double quotes 
    values <- gsub("\"([^\"]*)\"","\\1", regmatches(block, matches)[[1]][3,])
    cols <- regmatches(block, matches)[[1]][2,] 
    
    # paste all in a one_line data.frame
    as.data.frame(as.list(
      c(seqid = seqid,
        type = trimws(substr(text[1], 1,21)), 
        region = trimws(substr(text[1], 22,nchar(text[1]))),
        setNames(values, cols)))) 
  })
  # dplyr::bind_rows for binding all dataframes by col name 
  df <- dplyr::bind_rows(row_list)
  # if you want to extend "plasmid" you can use tidyr::fill
  # TODO: tidyr::fill(df, plasmid, .direction = "down")
})

# dplyr::bind_rows for building a one single data.frame
GBFF_df <- dplyr::bind_rows(GBFF_df)

head(GBFF_df)
#>        seqid   type                 region                    organism
#> 1 AE000783.1 source              1..910724 Borreliella burgdorferi B31
#> 2 AE000783.1   gene               105..677                        <NA>
#> 3 AE000783.1    CDS               105..677                        <NA>
#> 4 AE000783.1   gene  complement(768..1796)                        <NA>
#> 5 AE000783.1    CDS  complement(768..1796)                        <NA>
#> 6 AE000783.1   gene complement(1784..3249)                        <NA>
#>      mol_type strain                       type_material      db_xref locus_tag
#> 1 genomic DNA    B31 type strain of Borrelia burgdorferi taxon:224326      <NA>
#> 2        <NA>   <NA>                                <NA>         <NA>   BB_0001
#> 3        <NA>   <NA>                                <NA>         <NA>   BB_0001
#> 4        <NA>   <NA>                                <NA>         <NA>   BB_0002
#> 5        <NA>   <NA>                                <NA>         <NA>   BB_0002
#> 6        <NA>   <NA>                                <NA>         <NA>   BB_0003
#>   codon_start transl_table                                      product
#> 1        <NA>         <NA>                                         <NA>
#> 2        <NA>         <NA>                                         <NA>
#> 3           1           11               conserved hypothetical protein
#> 4        <NA>         <NA>                                         <NA>
#> 5           1           11 glycosyl hydrolase family 3 N domain protein
#> 6        <NA>         <NA>                                         <NA>
#>   protein_id
#> 1       <NA>
#> 2       <NA>
#> 3 AAC66406.1
#> 4       <NA>
#> 5 AAC66400.1
#> 6       <NA>
#>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    translation
#> 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         <NA>
#> 2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         <NA>
#> 3                                                                                                                                                            MILMKYSAILLICSVNLFCFQNKLTTSRWEFPKEDLIKKKIKIG IIYHNYINSIFYNENYKYIAFIGILTSYNEWIEIQFSPINFFTIPTNKDFISNTYFNL AFTIYITKYSILTDTLAIKFFIGTQIDLTLRTTIFTGKTTHAFLYPILPIITFKFEID FIPNNYSIYYKLSTSFKEFILLDLGISIFI
#> 4                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         <NA>
#> 5 MDFLKTFSFLFFSFFCLNLIAIESLPEIDYEYFNKDKSDLVDLI KFLGELDFQTILKDRNLFIGIRNLTNFKNVQELNIDDINRIKKINPIGIILFRENLKD AEQTKGLINAIKSHIGHDIFIAIDEEGGIVSRASENKKMGVYNFPAMEHVGGVKDLHL IYKIGEVLAKQLRRLGINLNMAPVADIKFAPHTPLLNRTFGGYSAYNIGLMVEAFIDG MQNNGVFSAIKHFPGLGGTTTDTHKYLAFLPYSKSFLMLNNFVPFVFGRAAKFIMIGH VNVPKISKDITSMSKSIVNIIRENLNITSIMMTDSYDMGAITRSFSNIENAIKKSLSS GVNIVLIP
#> 6                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         <NA>
#>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         note
#> 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       <NA>
#> 2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       <NA>
#> 3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       <NA>
#> 4                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       <NA>
#> 5                                                                                                                                                                                          identified by match to protein family HMM PF00933
#> 6 UTP--glucose-1-phosphate uridylyltransferase subfamily, authentic frameshift; this gene contains a frame shift which is not the result of sequencing error; identified by similarity to GB:AAB93994.1; match to protein family HMM PF01704
#>   pseudo gene EC_number ribosomal_slippage EC_number.1 plasmid
#> 1   <NA> <NA>      <NA>               <NA>        <NA>    <NA>
#> 2   <NA> <NA>      <NA>               <NA>        <NA>    <NA>
#> 3   <NA> <NA>      <NA>               <NA>        <NA>    <NA>
#> 4   <NA> <NA>      <NA>               <NA>        <NA>    <NA>
#> 5   <NA> <NA>      <NA>               <NA>        <NA>    <NA>
#> 6        <NA>      <NA>               <NA>        <NA>    <NA>
```

Comment: Oops. You're correct, filling the "source" information for each seqid was supposed to be the next step. That is a perfect solution, thank you very much!

Comment: Your code has been fantastic for a first attempt. However, for some bacterial GBFF files, I am unable to make the GBFF_df (e.g., https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCA/000/470/885/GCA_000470885.1_RhoBCP1_1.0/GCA_000470885.1_RhoBCP1_1.0_genomic.gbff.gz). It looks like the problem is specifically with creating the row_list for GBFF_df. I've been unable to debug the issue if you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is to late but I wrote and R package that can process .gbk files in R. Using the below script I think I was able to get close to what you want. The key is to safe each list in the GBFFfeat as an individual .gbk file including the FEATURES line at the top. You can then load the directory and process the .gbk files using the `read_gbk` and `gbk_features_to_df` functions from my package.

```r
library(tidyverse)

install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("nvelden/geneviewer")

library(geneviewer)

GBFFraw <- readGBFF("~/Downloads/GCA_000008685.2_ASM868v2_genomic.gbff.gz")

# read gbff file with readLines and split into a list of separate genbank records
readGBFF <- function (file, text = readLines(file), verbose = FALSE){
  if (is(text, "character")) {
    split_indices <- cumsum(grepl("^LOCUS", text))
    text <- base::split(text, split_indices)
  }
  return(text)
}

# assign accession numbers to the names of each genbank record
names(GBFFraw) <- sapply(GBFFraw, function(x) {
  version_line <- x[grep("^VERSION", x)]
  gsub("VERSION\\s+", "", version_line)
})

# capture the features for each genbank record
GBFFfeat <- lapply(GBFFraw, function(x) {
  i_start <- grep("^FEATURES", x)
  i_end <- grep("^ORIGIN", x)
  paste0(x[(i_start[1]):(i_end[1]-1)]) # INCLUDE THE FEATURES LINE
})

################################################################################

# Save each as a .gbk file
save_directory <- "~/path/to/folder/"

# Iterate over the list
for (name in names(GBFFfeat)) {
  # Create a file path from the directory and the list element's name
  file_path <- file.path(save_directory, paste0(name, ".gbk"))

  # Write the content to the file
  writeLines(GBFFfeat[[name]], file_path)
}

file_path <- "~/Downloads/gbk_files/"

gbk <- read_gbk(file_path)

CDS_df <- gbk_features_to_df(
  gbk, feature = "CDS",
  keys = c("region", "locus_tag", "protein_id") # Any other key you need
  ) 

gene_df <- gbk_features_to_df(
  gbk, feature = "gene", 
  key = c("region", "gene", "locus_tag") # Any other key you need
  )

head(CDS_df)
#>                   region locus_tag protein_id    cluster     strand start  end
#> 1               105..677   BB_0001 AAC66406.1 AE000783.1    forward   105  677
#> 2  complement(768..1796)   BB_0002 AAC66400.1 AE000783.1 complement   768 1796
#> 3             3419..5188   BB_0004 AAC66399.2 AE000783.1    forward  3419 5188
#> 4 complement(5251..6306)   BB_0005 AAC66398.2 AE000783.1 complement  5251 6306
#> 5 complement(6309..7397)   BB_0006 AAC66397.2 AE000783.1 complement  6309 7397
#> 6 complement(7458..8315)   BB_0007 AAC66404.1 AE000783.1 complement  7458 8315
head(gene_df)
#>                   region locus_tag gene    cluster     strand start  end
#> 1               105..677   BB_0001 <NA> AE000783.1    forward   105  677
#> 2  complement(768..1796)   BB_0002 <NA> AE000783.1 complement   768 1796
#> 3 complement(1784..3249)   BB_0003 <NA> AE000783.1 complement  1784 3249
#> 4             3419..5188   BB_0004 <NA> AE000783.1    forward  3419 5188
#> 5 complement(5251..6306)   BB_0005 trpS AE000783.1 complement  5251 6306
#> 6 complement(6309..7397)   BB_0006 <NA> AE000783.1 complement  6309 7397
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-24 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>